# changing application name in manifest after app published

Tags: android, google-play

Is it ok to change application name after it has been published?

```
<application
        android:name="com.domain.newname"
        ...
```

so that apk can be properly uploaded to the store as an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely....you just cannot change the package name. It's not recommended, but it's definitely possible/allowed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question was "Can I...", and my answer was "Yes...". How is that not answering the question?

Comment: I see. By the way it was an automatic comment after reviewing in http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/